# Notified about my own answer to my question

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, notifications

I suppose this isn't so much of a bug as an annoyance.  Yesterday afternoon I checked my email and had a "1 question has 1 answer on ServerFault" email.  I got excited (too excited probably), in hopes of having gotten a good answer.  When I opened the email, though, the answer was one I had posted to my own question.  I understand that answering your own question is likely a rare occurrence, but notification shouldn't be sent in that case.  After all, the asker knows s/he answered the question, no?

Answer (score 3):

Did you answer under a different account? Maybe you could provide a link to the question in question, perchance??

edit:

here's the only account I could find for you:

https://serverfault.com/users/9735

maybe this question?

[Splunk form search with multiple variables](https://serverfault.com/questions/26837/splunk-form-search-with-multiple-variables)

Comment: Yeah Jeff, it was the splunk search question.  Also, I do only have 1 account.

Comment: Jeff, I have just seen the same behaviour with a question I asked on Super User.  Strangely(?) the e-mail was not sent until nearly 2 days after I answered.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this doesn't raise a notification on your own recent activity page. I have never had a chance to actually see if that is the case using the email notifications. If so that would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me on StackOverflow when I answered my own question here:

> [Can I specify a range with the IntegerValidator attribute on a custom ConfigurationSection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109502)

The email basically contains my own answer to this question, presumably because I've not yet marked it as accepted - I guess I should have turned off alerts for that question, but I wanted to leave it open for a while to see if anyone had any better ideas.

I don't have enough rep to edit the question to mark this as a bug ;)