# If you answer your own question on SO, you shouldn't receive an email telling you that you answered it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

As the title says.

**EDIT**: or at least, there should be an option to turn this notification on or off.

Comment: What if you forget? Wouldn't that just be handy dandy?

Comment: +1 - I love how google doesn't send you the mails you send to a group you belong to

Comment: @Juan: you will be surprised that many people love to receive their own emails in their inbox on top of the sent folder. :p

Comment: Those people are just crazy

Comment: fyi- this is a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/notified-about-my-own-answer-to-my-question

Answer (score 2):

If these feature is implemented, there will be some who complain 'why no email after they answer their own qn'. And they ask for a new option 'email me even if it is from me to me'. Well, I wouldn't want to continue what comes next....

Comment: A Reply To All feature no doubt.

Comment: If you answer your own question, accept your answer, comment on both your question and your answer, and favorite it, you should get a specific badge named after you.